# DB & context too many errors

Tags: go

I am running below "go" code and getting lots of error :

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"    
    "github.com/get-ion/ion"
    "github.com/get-ion/ion/context"
    "github.com/get-ion/ion/view"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
    app := ion.New()
    app.RegisterView(view.HTML("./templates", ".html"))

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:password@/database?charset=utf8&parseTime=true&loc=Local")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
        panic("There was an error handling mysql connection!")
    }
    defer db.Close()

    allRoutes := app.Party("/", logThisMiddleware)
    {
        allRoutes.Get("/", homePage(db))
    }
}

func logThisMiddleware(ctx context.Context) {
    ctx.Application().Logger().Infof("Path: %s | IP: %s\n", ctx.Path(), ctx.RemoteAddr())
    ctx.Next()
}

func homePage(db *sql.DB) {
    func(ctx context.Context) {
       var (
            id             int
            title          string
            featured_image string
            created_at     string
        )
        rows, err := db.Query("SELECT id, title, featured_image, created_at from blogs order by crated_at desc limit 0,5")
        if err != nil {
            ctx.Application().Logger().Fatalf("MySQL Error fetching row %s\n", err)
        }
        defer rows.Close()
        blogData := map[int]map[int]string{}
        for rows.Next() {
            err := rows.Scan(&id, &title, &featured_image, &created_at)
            if err != nil {
                ctx.Application().Logger().Fatalf("Error while fetching row from blog: %s\n", err)
            }
            blogData[id][0] = title
            blogData[id][1] = featured_image
            blogData[id][2] = created_at
        }
        err = rows.Err()
        if err != nil {
            ctx.Application().Logger().Fatalf("Error while scanning Row : %s\n", err)
        }
        ctx.ViewData("blog", blogData)
        ctx.View("homepage.html")
    }
}
```

Errors are :-

```
./main.go:40: homePage(db) used as value
./main.go:50: func literal evaluated but not used
```

All the values are fetched as mentioned in : http://go-database-sql.org/retrieving.html , Still not sure why undefined variable issue. I don't think, these variables are required to be created, but if in case it has to be , please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ./main.go:40: homePage(db) used as value

homePage is void function. So you can't use it in function arguments.

> ./main.go:50: func literal evaluated but not used

```
func homePage(db *sql.DB) {
    func(ctx context.Context) {
        ...
    }
    return ""
}
```

This is broken syntax. I suggest you to go https://tour.golang.org/

> ./main.go:79: too many arguments to return
>       have (string)
>       want ()

As I said in above, homePage is void function. So you can't use return with value. Below is code which I could suppose your code should be.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"

    "github.com/get-ion/ion"
    "github.com/get-ion/ion/context"
    "github.com/get-ion/ion/view"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
    app := ion.New()
    app.RegisterView(view.HTML("./templates", ".html"))

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:password@/database?charset=utf8&parseTime=true&loc=Local")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
        panic("There was an error handling mysql connection!")
    }
    defer db.Close()

    allRoutes := app.Party("/", logThisMiddleware)
    {
        allRoutes.Get("/", homePage(db))
    }

    //app.Run(ion.Addr(":8080"))
}

func logThisMiddleware(ctx context.Context) {
    ctx.Application().Logger().Infof("Path: %s | IP: %s\n", ctx.Path(), ctx.RemoteAddr())
    ctx.Next()
}

func homePage(db *sql.DB) context.Handler {
    return func(ctx context.Context) {
        var (
            id             int
            title          string
            featured_image string
            created_at     string
        )
        rows, err := db.Query("SELECT id, title, featured_image, created_at from blogs order by crated_at desc limit 0,5")
        if err != nil {
            ctx.Application().Logger().Fatalf("MySQL Error fetching row %s\n", err)
        }
        defer rows.Close()
        blogData := map[int]map[int]string{}
        for rows.Next() {
            err := rows.Scan(&id, &title, &featured_image, &created_at)
            if err != nil {
                ctx.Application().Logger().Fatalf("Error while fetching row from blog: %s\n", err)
            }
            blogData[id][0] = title
            blogData[id][1] = featured_image
            blogData[id][2] = created_at
        }
        err = rows.Err()
        if err != nil {
            ctx.Application().Logger().Fatalf("Error while scanning Row : %s\n", err)
        }
        ctx.ViewData("blog", blogData)
        ctx.View("homepage.html")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, my mistake I forgot to update code here for `return ""` , now removed and updated code and error. About `void` function how can I reference `db` to function ? I don't want to open "db" connection inside every function. I just want to reference it from main. Is it possible ?

Comment: homePage should return context.Handler.

Comment: Yes I have already done that. But my error is on `homePage(db)` , is there any way, I can reference db from `main` function to `homePage` function ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also, how can I create variable where database column name has `_` (underscore) and fetch from database. As `go` warns me not to create variable with `_` in it. SnakeCase / CamelCase does not work while fetching from mysql.

Comment: Sure! Thanks for helping out until here.